# Display CV Link (Traditional View) Option no longer available?

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story

So I've tried looking around for a possible duplicate but nothing similar. I'm not sure if I'm the only one experiencing this also.

Before, I enabled the option to display the  <kbd>Link to My Developer CV Here</kbd>  to show in my profile. The link was visible to the public and directs to my CV (traditional view). Everything was okay.

But recently, I noticed that the link was no longer there. The only thing I remember changing in my Profile Settings was in the **Career** section. Instead of *Just <3 Code*, I selected *Work* and filled-out the fields (*Current Position and Company Name*). I saved and applied the changes.

At first I didn't notice it, but I think that was around the time the link is no longer visible. Thinking that it was maybe because the *Work* option was selected, I tried to set the Profile Settings back as it was.

Selected the *Just <3 Code* and leaving the optional field empty. Saved and applied the changes. Got back to my Profile and clicked on the  <kbd>Link to My Developer CV Here</kbd> , then it directs me back to the **Edit Profile & Settings** tab, where (*if I remember it correctly*) the checkbox to display the CV link is visible, but it's no longer there.

Is this as expected because the Developer Story is already implemented? I still see the  <kbd>Link to My Developer CV Here</kbd>  button when viewing my own profile, so I thought it was still available:

[image]

Does enabling the Developer Story tab the only option? I'm fairly sure that in the mail sent by StackOverflow, that even though the Developer Story will be enabled, the traditional view is still available.

Comment: For some reason, a downvote was made. Pretty sure that the post shows research effort and is quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for catching this! A fix is incoming with our next production build.

We removed CV related actions like the checkbox to display the CV link with the rollout of the Developer Story. Therefore the "Link To My Developer CV" button that you were seeing should have also been deprecated.

The traditional view is still available, and can be accessed through your public link even if your developer story tab is hidden (Edit Profile & Settings > Developer Story Preferences > Public link).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the info. :) Just one quick question, will the *Link to My Developer CV* still be available next time? Or will it just be for the Developer Story (*Link to My Developer Story*)?

Comment: This will not be available in the future.

Comment: I see. Thanks again for your time. :) Regards to the whole StackOverflow team. :D

Comment: No problem! Just an FYI that I edited my comment above since we decided today to remove that button altogether.